# How to convert xml data into csv/excel/table in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

we need to convert XML data into csv/excel/table in Azure cloud.

below is the sample xml code.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<SOAP-ENV:Body>
           <ns2:getProjectsResponse
               xmlns:ns2="http://www.logic8.com/eq/webservices/generated">
               <ns2:Project>
                   <ns2:fileName>P10001</ns2:fileName>
                   <ns2:alias>project1</ns2:alias>
               </ns2:Project>
               <ns2:Project>
                   <ns2:fileName>P10002</ns2:fileName>
                   <ns2:alias>project2</ns2:alias>
               </ns2:Project>
       <ns2:Project>
                   <ns2:fileName>P10003</ns2:fileName>
                   <ns2:alias>project3</ns2:alias>
               </ns2:Project>
           </ns2:getProjectsResponse>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
   </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Expected output:

[image: output]

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this way, firstly [convert xml to json](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/archive/blogs/mioteg/converting-xml-to-json-with-azure-logic-apps?utm_content=bufferadeeb&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer#converting-to-json) then use create csv table action to implement it.  The below is my test flow.

[image]

I use blob to get the xml content. The `Compose` action input is `json(xml(body('Get_blob_content')))`, then will get thejson data. Then is the `Create CSV table` From, ause the from data should be array, so it should be `outputs('Compose')['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']['SOAP-ENV:Body']['ns2:getProjectsResponse']['ns2:Project']`.

The last thing is customize the header and the value, the `ProjectID` value should be `item()['ns2:fileName']` and the `ProjectDescription` should be `item()['ns2:alias']`.

And here is the flow output, suppose this is what you want, hope this could help you.

[image]

Comment: Can you suggest me how to get file from azure data lake gen 2 in Logic App

Comment: Check this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/37118125-connector-for-azure-data-lake-gen-2), there is a comment looks like Blob Storage connector could work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any experience with Azure?  I ask because from your question it sounds like you’re not sure where to start or which service to use.  I’m also curious if you were given a requirement to use Azure or you thought Azure might be the solution yourself.  Also where is this XML coming from?  It looks like a SOAP request.

If you are a developer I’d consider authoring a Web App in .Net, it can use MVC, Core, Web APIs, and use it to consume this SOAP request and translate it and save the file.
For this I’d consider using an XMLDocument class to load the XML and parse through it.

But if you absolutely need to use Azure, the closest thing that would help automate this is Azure Logic Apps.  It offers many “no-code” solutions to plug in connectors that can transform and save data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-transform#how-to-use-a-transform

If you elaborate on your situation I’d be happy to offer further solutions

Comment: yes you are correct the response is from a SOAP service and we did calls through azure data factory and stored in data lake gen2. Now the requirement is to convert xml as shown into a table or csv in azure. As data factory cannot support xml format data, we need a solution in azure where we can convert